# How to use NSFetchedResultsController for scrolling bottom to top in messaging app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building a message app. When I am messaging in my application all the messages are getting store in core data. I have connected the core data with `TableViewController` with `NSFetchedResultsController`. I know how does this work and I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` for a long time with TableView. In most of the case `TableView load from top and it's scroll down to load more data on requirement`, thus my application works pretty well.

Here for the message app the TableView behaviour is opposite from the previous one. It loads the `last messages(20-30 batch size)` and if I want to see the old message I will scroll top. So I am trying to implement this on NSFetchedResultsController.

Example :
   Suppose I have 100 messages. I am setting batch size is 10. So first it will load `90-100` messages and it will scroll down to the last indexpath(here 100th). Then If I want want to scroll top and reach 90th indexpath it will give me 10 again so now I have `80-100` messages now it won't scroll down it will be keep on doing the same thing is I scroll to top.

I know I can sort in reverse order but that time I will get 100-90 but it won't so the last message(100) bellow.

So how can I fix this issue? Any configuration is there for `NSFetchedResultsController` that I am missing? How to fix?

Comment: did you find any solution, if yes please post answer

Comment: No, I have written a custom fetch controller to interact with the coredata. It is working fine now.

Comment: i'll really appreciate, if you can post the code of custom fetch controller.

Comment: @Nullify can you share the custom fetch controller solution with us. We are also facing similar issue.

Comment: @AnkitThakur I don't have the code as of now as this was posted 3 years back. If possible please create a sample project and share the github link. I can help you on that.